# Integración Klarna en web PHP a medida sin framework, ni gestor de paquetes (composer) ni librerías externas

Tags: php

Buenas estamos intentando integrar los pagos a plazos de Klarna pero no vemos ningún ejemplo en PHP sin librerías ni usamos en este proyecto gestores de paquetes como 'composer', había un SDK PHP Api de Klarna pero está actualmente deprecado.

Github Klarna filtrando PHP
https://github.com/orgs/klarna/repositories?q=&type=all&language=php

Klarna SDK PHP
https://klarna.github.io/kco_rest_php/

Espero que alguien nos pueda decir por donde tirar,
Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Parece que ya no dan soporte a PHP directamente, a menos que sea en plataformas específicas. Aunque puedes intentar integrarla en [stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/klarna/accept-a-payment).

Comment: La idea es pagar sólo Klarna, no Stripe y Klarna a la vez.

Comment: Entonces tocará descargar un plugin, por ejemplo el de Wordpress, ver como funciona y crear tu propio script.